# A program that sorts strings alphabetically without compare.To (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

I'm attempting to write a program that  is supposed to sort two strings alphabetically, and if s1 comes before s2, return -1, if s1 comes after s2, return 1, and if they are the same word, print 0. So for s1 = "king" and s2 = "kink", it should print -1.  I've managed to implement this for words that do not start with the same letter, but for words that do not, such as "king" and "kink" I'm encountering difficulties.

```
public static int compare(String a, String b)
  {

int comparison = 0;
int c1, c2;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++) 
{
    c1 = (int) a.toLowerCase().charAt(i);   
    c2 = (int) b.toLowerCase().charAt(i);   
    comparison = c1 - c2; 

    if(comparison == 0) 
    {
      if(a.length() > b.length())    
         return 1;
      else if (a.length() < b.length())
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
    }
    else if (comparison > 0)
      return 1;
    else  
      return -1;

}

return comparison;
 }
```

I feel like the issue is with my for loop, that I'm not allowing it to go through the entire the string, but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: Instead of return `0`, when the `comparision` is equal to `0` - you should try using `continue`.

Comment: i think you better use watch values for each loop so that you can determine what you are getting in each loop. or you can print the c1 and c2 value in each loop so that you could find if you are getting expected result ..

Comment: @Tirath thanks for the help, now it can alphabetize "king" and "king" etc. appropriately.  It doesn't seem to recognize spaces now, though, for example "hello" and "hello " returns 0 when it's required to return -1.  Any ideas?

Comment: @jdhw Yes. You have designed the `for` loop to work with `strings` of equal length. I think, you should try modifying your code to execute the `for` loop based on the value of `comparision`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null) {
        return b == null ? 0 : -1;
    } else if (b == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    String alow = a.toLowerCase();
    String blow = b.toLowerCase();
    int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int d = alow.charAt(i) - blow.charAt(i);
        if (d != 0) {
            return d < 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    int diff = a.length() - len;
    if (diff != 0) {
        return diff < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```